# Passing parameter dynamically to YouTube API using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, youtube-api

I am making a YouTube API request like this:

```
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
    part: "contentDetails",
    id: "somestring",
    key: "MY-API-KEY"
} /*, ...*/ )
```

I have a hidden field with the value `id`. The user can choose if they want to use `id` or `forUsername`.

If I use the jQuery code below I get an error:

> unexpected string

and from the API parameter is missing but the value is `id` in this case.

```
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
    part: "contentDetails",
    $("#subtype").val(): $("#url").val(),
    key: "MY-API-KEY"
}, /*, ...*/ )
```

How can I use the jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new ES6 object initializer syntax for this:

```
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
    part: "contentDetails",
    [$("#subtype").val()]: $("#url").val(),
    key: "MY-API-KEY"
})
```

Notice the square brackets around computed property name. If you want to support browsers that do not support ES6 then use a simpler approach:

```
var params = {
    part: "contentDetails",
    key: "MY-API-KEY"
};
params[$("#subtype").val()] = $("#url").val();
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises ES6 object like this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  username / id:
  <select id="subtype">
    <option value="ForUsername">username</option>
    <option value="id">id</option> 
  </select>
  <br> Last name: <input type="text" id="url"><br>
  <button type="button" id="searchButton">Click Me!</button>
  <script>
    $("#searchButton").click(function() {
      var paramsChooseByUser = $("#subtype").val();
      var paramsValue = $("#url").val();
      $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
          part: "id",
          [paramsChooseByUser]: paramsValue,
          key: 'someValidKey'
        })
        .always(function(data) {
          console.log(data.responseJSON);
        });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your time and effort the answer above you was good enough